# SCSS - Conditional include not working and all the blocks gets executed

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to do conditional include in scss. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="test" data-active data-label data-comment >1</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-label>2</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-comment >3</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-comment data-label>4</div>
<div class="test" data-active>5</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.test[data-active]{

  background : red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  $margin: 0px;
  &[data-label]{
    background : blue;
    $margin: $margin + 10px;
  }
  &[data-comment]{
    background: yellow;
    $margin: $margin + 10px;
  }
  &[something]{
    $margin: $margin + 100px;
  }
  margin-right : $margin;
}
```

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/gaurav-neema/pen/VwpPBxY

In the code, you can see that even if the element does not contain the attribute, all the blocks get executed and the margin is included.

Can anyone help in indentifying what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3):

You are redefining `$margin` every time, you cannot use selectors like `if` statements.

Redefining with:

- `$margin: $margin + 10px;`
- `$margin: $margin + 100px;`

You are setting all `margin-right: 100px;`

I think you might want:

SCSS

```
$margin: 0px;

.test[data-active] {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  &[data-label] {
    background : blue;
    margin: $margin + 10px;
  }

  &[data-comment] {
    background: yellow;
    margin: $margin + 10px;
  }

  &[something] {
    margin: $margin + 100px;
  }

  margin-right: $margin;
}
```

Comment: I thought the block will only get executed if the attribute exists in the element. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It all gets "executed" as it all gets rendered into your CSS, but it would only apply if the selector that gets rendered applies to your markup.

Comment: Idk what your specific need is for a variable `$margin` especially since its `0` but you're adding to it, so you could just skip the addition and just set it directly. If your intent is to change the base `$margin` value then you could still add it together and apply it inside each selector.

Comment: I just added the margin for the purpose of demo. What I do need is to include the icon(s) selectively based on the attributes.

Comment: It's also best practice to keep all properties that apply to a selector together, so your margin-right at the bottom should right after the `display: inline-block;`. AND MAYBE your intent is that the lower selectors should be `margin-right: $margin + 10px;` etc.

Comment: Are you planning to use icons with an @include or an @extend? Define that above all this and use it in your selector, e.g. `&[data-label] { @include icon-label; }` etc

Comment: I understand how this all works. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is CSS custom properties. SCSS is not dynamic and there for renders at compile. CSS custom properties are dynamic so they get applied once the condition is for filled, meaning when your class is applied it will change the value then.

Read about the difference at:

- [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/)

Read about CSS custom properties at:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)
- [ishadeed.com](https://ishadeed.com/article/practical-css-variables/)
- [daverupert.com](https://daverupert.com/2020/10/variable-layers/)

This is just 3 of so many articles about the subject.

Now demo time, I changed the property to be `background-color` to make it more clear for the demo.

```css
.test[data-active] {
  --background-color: aqua;

  background: var(--background-color);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.test[data-label] {
  --background-color: deeppink;
}

.test[data-something] {
  --background-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-active data-label data-comment>1</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-label>2</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-comment>3</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-comment data-label>4</div>
<div class="test" data-active data-something>5</div>
```